# How to Overlay Two PDFs in LaTeX with Adjustable Opacity?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf, overleaf, pdfpages

I am working on a project where I need to overlay two PDF documents in LaTeX and control the opacity of each layer. Specifically, I want to include two PDF pages in a single page and adjust how much of each PDF is visible. I am familiar with basic LaTeX commands but haven't done anything like this before.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Are there specific packages or commands in LaTeX that can overlay PDFs with adjustable opacity settings? Any example codes or references to similar projects would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain specifically what yuo mean by `adjust how much of each PDF is visible`.

Comment: I mean for example, I want the header to be from the 1st pdf and the footer from the 2nd pdf. I want to know how I can determine this thing. @daleif

Comment: That is probably a job for tikz then. But you will have to manually code it. It sounds a bit strange to me to take the header from one doc and apply it to another.

Answer (score 2):

A tip by superimposing a more or less opaque filled rectangle on the PDF.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{landscape}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(img){\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{imagePDF.pdf}};
\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=0.2] (img.north east) rectangle (img.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(img){\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{imagePDF.pdf}};
\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=0.8] (img.north east) rectangle (img.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following `pdflatex` example uses `TikZ`. Three figures are overlapped with various transparencies: (1) The leftmost figure is drawn fully opaque and shows how the original figure should look like. (2) The right figure is overlaid with an alpha value of 0.75, but in a way that each object of the original figure is independently made translucent. (3) Finally, the third figure is put inside a transparency group and made translucent as a whole. Most probably you want to use the latter when overlaying your PDF documents.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (N1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{figure.pdf}};
  \node[opacity=.75] (N2) at (3cm,0) {\includegraphics{figure.pdf}};
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.75]
    \node (N3) at (1.5 cm,-3cm) {\includegraphics{figure.pdf}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Explanation

The `opacity` key in TiKZ given to a drawing command sets the **current alpha** value for both stroke operations (like drawing a line) and other painting operations (like filling areas or painting a bitmap image). Its value is within 1.0 (opaque, default) and 0.0 (transparent).

In the right figure (the second inclusion, node N2), every line or area is stroked or filled with translucent colors, even those that are intended to obscure other parts of the figure (and designers often use covering instead of clipping). See example below: the blue square with letter B at the right does not cover the underlying dotted red circle (the arc between 12 o'clock and 3 o'clock), and the "Hidden text" below letter A is also revealed. Also, if the included PDF already used transparency, it would override our settings, and reset the opaqueness to whatever value given in the original file. This is usually not what one wants.

The bottom figure (the third inclusion, node N3) is placed inside a so called **transparency group**. It is essentially a `scope` environment with the option `transparency group` and an opacity value. The figure is first painted normally, then made translucent as a whole. Thus the "Hidden text" under letter A is not revealed, and the blue square correctly hides the red arc. The red arc below letter B comes from the second inclusion (the arc between 6 and 7 o'clock). This is what one usually wants. Probably, you want to put both your included PDFs in separate transparency groups. Instead of `opacity`, you may also want to try the `blend mode=multiply` option within the transparency group. This will mix the included PDF images without tinting them with the white background.

[image: Results of overlapping included figures]

In example above, the sample input `figure.pdf` is generated by the following code:

```latex
%%% This is figure.tex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={45mm,45mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[scale=2, anchor=north, align=center] (C) at (current page) {Hidden\\text};
\node[circle, draw, line width=10pt, color=red, loosely dotted, fill=green!20, 
    scale=6] (A) at (current page) {A};
\node[draw, line width=12pt, color=blue!50!black, fill=white, anchor=north east,
    scale=4, outer sep=1.5pt] (B) at (current page.north east) {B}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```